# AngularJS code not working after ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page where we get a list of users using angular $http from backend as shown below.

```
myApp.controller("MyCntrl", function ($scope, $http) {
   $scope.users= [];
   $scope.countries = function () {
        $http.get(url).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            return data;
        });
    };

   $scope.getUsers = function () {
        $http.get(url).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.users= data;
        });
    };
});
```

And my html is like:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCntrl" ng-init="getUsers()">
  <p ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.UserName}}</p>

  <select>
      <option ng-repeat="country in countries">{{country.CountryName}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Everything is working fine up to displaying users.

But the code after ng-repeat of users is not working. I'm not able to see the list of countries in the dropdown. 
I can see the json list of both users and countries in firebug.
Can anyone help me on this?

My countries Json is

```
[{CountryId:1,CountryName:"India"}]
```

What i've observed is that the angular code is not working after the first ng-repeat of users.
When i try to see the length of countries json like

```
<p>{{countries.length}}</p>
```

It is just printing {{countries.length}} in browser

Comment: `return = data;` ? Set the scope variable for countries as you have done for _users_

Comment: post your json of contries

Comment: @RayonDabre sorry its typo. Its return data;

Comment: you are missing the point regardless of typo or not ... return inside success is usesless

Comment: @Aravind You have defined `countries` to be a function, not an Array/Object.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead in the case of `<select>`:

```
<select ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="country.countryName for country in countriesData">
</select>
```

**Edit**:

Replace this:

```
$scope.countries = function () {
  $http.get(url).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    return data;
  });
};
```

By this:

```
$http.get(url).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  $scope.countriesData = data;
});
```

NOTE: Checked that `url` is defined !

Comment: can't use ng-options without ng-model. Also `return` inside `success does nothing

Comment: Thanks. Updated my answer

Comment: That `return` inside success is the code that I am pointing out to be replaced.

Comment: ah yes..my bad regarding the return

Answer (score 0):

You can set the returned data for `$scope.countries` just as you've done for `$scope.users`, except you don't need to define a function that you'd *call in your view* to get all the countries.

Instead, call this function in your controller which in turn will set the `countries` variable into the scope:

```
this.getCountries = function () {
    $http.get(url).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.countries = data;
    });
};

// call the method to get the countries 
this.getCountries();
```

*Note that in your code you have `return = data` which might be causing a syntax error.*

Answer (score 0):

You have call function in ng-repeat that's why its not working properly.Correct code should be like below

```
myApp.controller("MyCntrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.users= [];
    $scope.getCountry = function () {
        $http.get(url).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.countries = data;
       });
    };

    $scope.getUsers = function () {
        $http.get(url).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
           $scope.users= data;
           $scope.getCountry();
        });
    };
});
```